# Is adding a paver patio or flower garden near a home foundation a bad idea?

Tags: basement, patio, landscaping, gardening

More specifically, should I be concerned about creating drainage issues?

We already have some leaks in our basement. I'd like to avoid creating additional problems.

Comment: I don't think there's any blanket yes or no to patios near foundations, but you should keep drainage in mind when you design it. Make sure you're directing water away from the foundation rather than toward it, and you're not blocking any existing drainage paths. I think photos or drawings of what you have in mind would get you better answers.

Comment: How do you do you direct water away?

Comment: That's a whole question of its own. There are many ways, the simplest and most obvious being sloping a patio slightly so waters runs away from the house.